# Node.js v0.10.18 Mongoose validation falls over on method 'captureStackTrace'"

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I'm trying to use validation provided by Mongoose, so have a scheme

```
var MeecaptureStackTracetingSchema = new Schema({
 title: {type: String, required : true}
....
```

Trying to save without setting the title - gets to the below point, Mongoose wants to return the error for the missing fields but falls over with " no method 'captureStackTrace'"

```
/mongoose/lib/error.js
function MongooseError (msg) { // Validator "required" failed for path title with value `undefined`
  Error.call(this);
  Error.captureStackTrace(this, arguments.callee); // Falls over here
  this.message = msg;
  this.name = 'MongooseError';
};
```

Throws this error

```
TypeError: Object function model(doc, fields, skipId) {
    if (!(this instanceof model))
      return new model(doc, fields, skipId);
    Model.call(this, doc, fields, skipId);
  } has no method 'captureStackTrace'
```

I set up a very basic test

```
function MyError(msg){
    this.name = 'MyError';
    this.message = msg;
    Error.call(this, msg);
    Error.captureStackTrace(this, this.constructor);
}

MyError('New error')
```

And that works fine. So is there someway I could have mashed `captureStackTrace` in my code set? I grepped it, and there aren't any obvious missuses of the name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Mongoose model I have declared a global variable Error, which made conflicts with native Error instance of Node. Renaming it to LogError helped.